# Converting directory-based rule into one patterned-matched rule

Tags: makefile

I have several rules in the form of

```
%.averaged_flow_profile.csv: \
%.PIVlab_data.mat \
%.parameters.csv \
%.PIVlab_set.mat \
%.roimask.tif \
%.processed.mp4 \
%.xml \
src/get_flowProfileFromPIV.R \
src/includes/middle_layer_flow_profile_theo.R
    src/get_flowProfileFromPIV.R $(dir $*) 


%.averaged_flow_profile.png: \
%.averaged_flow_profile.csv \
src/plot_flowProfile.R
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)figures/; $(filter %.R, $^) $(dir $*)

.SECONDEXPANSION:
data/flow_rate_measurements/220224: \
$$@/results/cooked/*/P220224.S220113C2.P4.averaged_flow_profile.csv \
$$@/results/cooked/*/P220224.S220113C2.P4.averaged_flow_profile.png
    echo "done!"
    
data/flow_rate_measurements/220421/P220421I01: \
$$@/results/cooked/*/P220421I01.averaged_flow_profile.csv \
$$@/results/cooked/*/P220421I01.averaged_flow_profile.png
    echo "done!"
    
data/flow_rate_measurements/220421/P220421I02: \
$$@/results/cooked/*/P220421I02.averaged_flow_profile.csv \
$$@/results/cooked/*/P220421I02.averaged_flow_profile.png
    echo "done!"
```

and have folder structures that I manually create

```
- data/flow_rate_measurements/
-- 220224/
--- 220224/results/cooked/
-- P220421I01
--- P220421I01/results/cooked/
-- P220421I02
--- P220421I02/results/cooked/
```

Is it possible to write the rules after `.SECONDEXPANSION` as a pattern such that I don't have to add a new rule for each directory under `data/flow_rate_measurements/`?

Comment: Is the first example here correct?  The output location is different than the others (doesn't have the `P220221` directory?  Before we can help we need to understand exactly how the targets and prerequisites are related.

Comment: Also, remember make runs in a directory where no built targets exist (at least the first time).  So you can't rely on directories existing that are created as part of the build, when you define rules (which are defined before any recipes are invoked).  Are these `results/cooked` things generated by some other rule?  _Somewhere_ in your makefile you need to define the original source files that everything derives from, and you need to define the translation steps between those files and the final target files.

Comment: Along the same line, are the direct subdirectories of the `results/cooked` folders created as part of the build?  Because attempting to match them via a wildcard will not do what you expect if they don't already exist at the beginning of a build.

Comment: @MadScientist, yes it is correct. the pattern is `data/flow_rate_measurements/<UID>`

Comment: no, `results/cooked` are generated manually. See the updated question

Comment: @JohnBollinger I create them myself manually before running the rule; see the updated question

Comment: I'm not sure I understand these rules.  By having the prerequisites be subedirectories of `$$@` you are are specifying _target_ is a directory, which must already exist obviously since its prerequisites are subdirectories.  Is it really the goal that every time one of these prerequisite files has been updated more recently than the modification time of the parent directory, you re-run the recipe?

Comment: no it is not, but I just didn't want to write rules for each individual analysis. For instance, under `P220421I02/results/cooked/`, I have several similar folders, each using the same dataset inside `P220421I02` but analysing it with different parameters (hence the wildcard in `$$@/results/cooked/*/P220421I02...`)

Comment: @MadScientist I'm open to suggestions if you have any

Comment: I'm not talking about the prerequisites I'm talking about the target.  Your rules say "if the modification time on the directory `data/flow_rate_measurements/<UID>` is older than the modification time of any of the files provided, then run the recipe.  Else don't run the recipe."  That's a very unusual way to decide whether to run the recipe, but maybe it's what you want.  We can't give suggestions because you haven't explained clearly what behavior you actually want.  Maybe the clearest thing to do is try to write it out in English rather than pidgin makefile.